# Why am I getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.createLink is not a function at new Link at <anonymous>1:9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.createLink is not a function
    at new Link in JavaScript, the Paragraph class works perfectly fine.

```
class Paragraph {
constructor(text) {
  this.text = text;
  return this.createParagraph();
}
createParagraph() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
  return paragraph;
    }
}

class Link extends Paragraph {
constructor(text, link) {
    super(text);
    this.link = link;
    return this.createLink();
}
createLink() {
    var aLink = document.createElement('a');
    aLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
    aLink.href = this.link;
    return aLink;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to execute the following command: var a = new Link("Text","google.com"); as a test.

Comment: John, what are you trying to achieve? a dom with link and paragraph like what

Answer (score 2):

So the reason you're running into this issue is because of a strange property of the constructor.

This code:

```
constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
    return this.createParagraph();
}
```

causes the "this" in your Link constructor to actually be the result of `createParagraph`.

I honestly have no idea why the parent constructor behaves that way, but removing your "return" from both constructors should make this not error.

In general, constructors don't need to return anything, the instance you're creating is "returned" by default from the `new` operator.

Comment: And after some testing, the constructor appears to do this if an object is returned, but NOT a string. Which is also very confusing.

Answer (score -1):

The `super(text);` in your `Link` constructor calls the `constructor` of the `Paragraph` class. A new instance of the `Paragraph` is being created but instead of returning the instance, the value from the `createParagraph()` method is being returned.

So JavaScript is trying to create an extended class based on a value different from what it expects and then fails. But remember, JavaScript classes are not actually classes but an abstraction layer upon creating functions with prototypes.

But oddly enough, rebuilding it with regular function declarations (old skool way) does seem to let it work. I'm puzzled about this.

```js
function Paragraph(text) {
  this.text = text;
  return this.createParagraph();
}

Paragraph.prototype.createParagraph = function() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
  return paragraph;
}

function Link(text, link) {
  Paragraph.call(this, text);
  this.link = link;
  return this.createLink();
}

Link.prototype = Object.create(Paragraph.prototype);
Link.prototype.constructor = Link;

Link.prototype.createLink = function() {
  var aLink = document.createElement('a');
  aLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
  aLink.href = this.link;
  return aLink;
}

var link = new Link('hello', 'http://google.com');
console.log(link);
```

Although how you are using the `class` does not make any sense. Why not put everything just in a `function` if you only want to return a value, but not an instance.

The example below would make a lot more sense to build what you are currently trying.

```
function createParagraph(text) {
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return paragraph;
}

function createLink(text, link) {
  var aLink = document.createElement('a');
  aLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  aLink.href = link;
  return aLink;
}
```